# setting a div with an hidden data attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a unique `data-id` to every `div` that i have using the following code

```
$("<div>", {class:"myClass", data-id:"test"})
```

and to get this `data-id` back with this code

```
 $(".myClass").attr("data-id")
```

but for some reason I am getting the following error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

any ideas what am I doing worng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding quotes. change:

`data-id` to `"data-id"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change that first line of code.  `$("<div>", {class:"myClass", data-id:"test"})` doesn't work because the `-` is a special character. You need to either put it in quotes  like this: `'data-id'`, or choose a different name.

Comment: quick follow up if I want to dynamically add text to "data-id" can I just do toString(i)? assuming i is a number in a for loop?

Comment: @Quantico, I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you're asking if you need to use `toString` to make the `"data-id"` attribute equal to `i`, the answer is no. You just need to write in the `i`, like this: `{class:"myClass", "data-id": i}`.